# Process and TCPSocket not close properly in crystal

Tags: tcp, process, crystal-lang

I'm creating a tcp server who accept all the connection and execute incomming data has command line, but when i send "exit" to the tcpsocket, the process and the socket dont close properly

```
# main.cr

require "socket"

PORT = 2022

def handle_connection(socket)
  Process.run("/bin/sh", input: socket, output: socket, error: socket)
end

server = TCPServer.new(PORT)

loop do
  if socket = server.accept?
    spawn handle_connection(socket)
  else
    break
  end
end
```

for example, the following code work fine, after sending "exit" to STDIN, the shell is exiting, "process ending" is printedand the program close

```
channel = Channel(Nil).new

spawn do
  Process.run("/bin/sh", input: STDIN, output: STDOUT, error: STDERR)
  puts "process ending"
  channel.send(nil)
end

channel.receive
```

for debuggin purpose i have tested this code too but "process ending" was never print until i manually close the tcp socket

```
# main.cr

require "socket"

PORT = 2022

def handle_connection(socket)
  Process.run("/bin/sh", input: socket, output: socket, error: socket)
  puts "process ending"
end

server = TCPServer.new(PORT)

loop do
  if socket = server.accept?
    spawn handle_connection(socket)
  else
    break
  end
end
```

when i run main.cr, `nc localhost 2022` and send "exit" i expect the socket close properly but he dont, and when i send more command the program raise an error

```
Unhandled exception in spawn: Error writing file: Broken pipe (Errno)
  from /usr/lib/crystal/crystal/system/unix/file_descriptor.cr:79:13 in 'unbuffered_write'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/io/buffered.cr:122:14 in 'write'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/io.cr:1130:7 in 'copy'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/process.cr:413:7 in 'copy_io'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/process.cr:409:11 in 'copy_io:close_dst'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/process.cr:298:17 in '->'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/fiber.cr:255:3 in 'run'
  from /usr/lib/crystal/fiber.cr:47:34 in '->'
  from ???
```

Comment: There is no code here that *handles* the string 'exit'. What exactly are you expecting here? or asking?

Comment: Since your edt this remains true.

Comment: Because i bind the socket to the shell (/bin/sh) `Process.run("/bin/sh", input: socket, output: socket, error: socket)` and when the shell receive "exit" he must exit, in my 2nd example (whitout the socket, when i bind to stdin/out/err) , when i write "exit" to the stdin, the shell exit and the program close properly

Comment: I want to write a program that does the same job as `nc -l -p PORT --exec=/bin/sh` and when i exec `echo "exit" | nc localhost PORT` on another terminal, the socket close, not because nc have a particular handling for "exit" but because its how /bin/sh works, see `man exit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with Crystal. There is an issue open here:

https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/7810