# Is there a way to pipe IO?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to pipe 2 IO object, i come from nodejs and we can do something like that:

```
const child_process = require('child_process')

const shell = child_process.spawn('/bin/sh')

shell.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
shell.stdin.write('pwd\n')
shell.stdin.write('ls\n')
/* write all command i want */
```

and im looking for do the same thing in crystal

i know for the current example we can write

```
shell = Process.new("/bin/sh", input: Process::Redirect::Pipe, output: STDOUT, error: STDOUT)

shell.input << "ls\n"
shell.input << "pwd\n"
# all commands i want
```

but for some reason passing TCPSocket to Process.new input/output/error dont work very well (see here too if you have time [Process and TCPSocket not close properly in crystal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645972/process-and-tcpsocket-not-close-properly-in-crystal))

so im looking for an alternative way who will look like:

```
shell = Process.new("/bin/sh", input: Process::Redirect::Pipe, output: Process::Redirect::Pipe, Process::Redirect::Pipe)

shell.output.pipe(STDOUT) # not the crystal pipe but like the nodejs pipe

shell.input << "ls\n"
shell.input << "pwd\n"
# all commands i want
```

Comment: Have you looked into `IO#pipe`?
https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.29.0/IO.html#pipe(read_blocking=false,write_blocking=false,&block)-class-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IO.copy` inside a coroutine:

```
shell = Process.new("/bin/sh", input: :pipe, output: :pipe, error: :pipe)

spawn { IO.copy shell.output, STDOUT }
spawn { IO.copy shell.error, STDERR }

shell.input << "ls /\n"
shell.input << "pwd\n"

shell.wait
```

https://carc.in/#/r/75z4